# Grunt watch: Not triggering any task

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am trying to automate my workflow with the help of Grunt. I have everything set up, but the watch task is not working - I can start it, but it doesn't detect changes. The problem really must be in the watch task, as I can trigger the sass task by hand and it compiles correctly without problems.

My Gruntfile looks like this:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    'style': 'compressed'
                },
                expand: true,
                cwd: './sass/',
                src: 'style.scss',
                dest: './css/',
                ext: '.css'
            },
            dev: {
                options: {
                    'style': 'expanded',
                },
                expand: true,
                cwd: './sass/',
                src: 'style.scss',
                dest: './css/',
                ext: '.css'
            }
        },

        watch: {
            sass: {
                files: ['<%= sass.dev.src %>'],
                tasks: ['default']
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass:dev']);
};
```

The structure in the project directory looks like this:

```
Gruntfile.js
index.html
package.json
css
  > style.css (created by sass task)
node_modules
  > all required modules
sass
  > style.scss
```

To me everything looks good, but as it is not working something must be wrong. My guess it that the paths following the 'expand' option are off, although I already tried other structures that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `sass.dev.src` equals `src: 'style.scss'`. The watch task configured with `files: ['<%= sass.dev.src %>']` will try and watch `./style.scss` and *not* `./sass/style.scss`.

The watch task has a `cwd` option (`options:{cwd:'./sass'}`) but probably easier to just set it to watch `files: ['sass/*.scss']` instead.

Comment: Wow thank you! It seems simple, but I just couldn't find that problem. I'll guess for such a simple setup there is generally no need to use `expand`, `cwd` etc., right?

Comment: `expand` is useful if you want to compile files many-to-many, as opposed to many-to-one file. So `expand` isn't necessary if you want to compile down to a single `css/style.css` file, as you're doing in your example.

Comment: in my setup it detect file changes but not trigger any tasks, any advice?
i notice that specify non exist task not giving warning, but i verify that my task is valid and runnable from grunt

Comment: sorry already solve via [this](https://gist.github.com/brutalcrozt/83b0296a536cb923073b)